# Wix and MSMQ: MSMQ Detection

Tags: wix, msmq, wix3.5, wix-extension

I have to create a message queue if MSMQ is installed. If MSMQ is not installed then move forward without doing anything.

Is there a way, we can found that whether MSMQ is installed in MSMQExtension dll.

I know, We can use Registry for the same but installer will fail if MSMQ is not installed.

Comment: This will still fail, if you have included MSMQ WiX elements in your wxs markup. I believe, once we have the MSMQ WiX extension elements in the wxs file, the MSI database will create tables during compilation / linking. Since these  tables become part of MSI database, the built in custom actions get invoked. In case of MSMQ, it still tries to load mqrt.dll and hence will display pop ups during installation. I am also looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[How to tell if MSMQ is installed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/05/14/how-to-tell-if-msmq-is-installed.aspx)